Is the surface electron affinity of (tribasic) sodium- or calcium phosphate higher?
Let's imagine we have two polycrystalline samples: $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$ and $\ce{Na3PO4}$. A free electron is added to both. Some heat is released.
I wanted to check whether my reasoning about this scenario is correct. Could not find any data about this, though.
I already know that, for some other materials, surfaces' electron affinities depend on the crystal facet the electron went to. If this is the case here as well, I would accept this as a useful piece of information. However, maybe this is a negligible effect here.
Here's my attempt:

the free electron to be added to the surface cannot go to the negatively charged phosphate ion. It must be only attracted by $\ce{Na^+}$ or $\ce{Ca^2+}$ .
the ionic radii are similar.
$\ce{Ca^2+}$  has more charge per ion, therefore it may attract the added electron more.

Here's my issue:

There are twice as many $\ce{Na^+}$ ions per one phosphate compared to $\ce{Ca^2+}$ ions per phosphate. That makes me suspect, the added electron may rather be attracted to multiple $\ce{Na^+}$ simultaneously and occupy a larger volume or even conduction band instead. Larger orbital may lower its kinetic energy more, assuming this does not happen in $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$.

Which explanation is more plausible?

@Maurice There are two: 1) The electron goes to a local orbital in $\ce{Na3PO4}$. or 2) There are no such orbitals to go to in $\ce{Na3PO4}$, there is conduction band instead.

The title has only one question : * Is the surface electron affinity of (tribasic) sodium or calcium phosphate higher ? *

@Maurice If anybody has a direct answer to the question in title, that would be great! Searching the internet for measured values of surface electron affinities usually gives nothing.

Nobody has an answer to the question for two reasons : First, we don't know the meaning of the term "surface electron affinity" and second, we don't understand the end of the question which is : Higher. But higher than what ?

@Maurice OK. I see, this is an uncommon term. I mean the amount of heat released by a free electron upon attachment to the surface. By "higher", obviously is meant "which of the samples'  -- $\ce{Na3PO4}$ or $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$ 's electron affinity is higher than the other's.
